# what to do if you commit a sin in ramadan?

Tags: sin, ramadan

what to do if you commit a sin in ramadan and then you feel so ashamed to Allah that you can't even face him. like I cant bring myself to pray and ask for forgiveness because I asked Allah for forgiveness multiple times for same sin I make. I don't know what to do and how to bring myself to pray again. Are not devils locked up in ramadan than why am I making a sin even though I read Quran and pray 5 times a day but I still Made that sin made me hate myself. now I am avoiding salah thinking will Allah forgive me again? and feeling bad and ashamed in front of Allah.

Comment: How about asking Allah for forgiveness and repent?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we commit a sin, whether it's Ramadan or not, we should turn to Allah in repentance and beseech His forgiveness. We should never lose hope of His mercy. He is the All-Compassionate the All-Merciful. He is the Rahman Raheem. The Forgiving and The All-Forgiving, Ghafaar and Ghafoor. He loves forgiveness. It's the shaitaan that makes one feel such ashame that they will no longer turn to Allah for forgiveness or repent to Him because the shaitaan doesn't like it when we turn to Him in repentance. He doesn't want Allah to forgive us. He doesn't want us to enter Paradise. So he makes us feel hopeless of Allah's mercy. Yet Allah makes clear that we should never give up on His mercy and no sin is too great that He cannot forgive it. If we meet 4 conditions when we repent and ask for His forgiveness so we are doing it sincerely and with regret doing everything to not commit that sin again then there's absolutely no reason why He wouldn't forgive us, even if we fell into that sin again due to human weakness so long as the same 4 conditions are yet again met, as it's a part of His mercy. So long as we worship Him alone without any partners. That's the only sin, that if we die within without repentance and belief thereafter, He will never forgive. All other sins however bad they may seem; He will forgive.

> Do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful (The Qu'ran 39:53)

> Will they not turn to Allah in repentance and seek His forgiveness? And Allah is All-Forgiving, Most Merciful (Qu'ran 5:74)

> Whoever constantly seeks forgiveness from Allah, Allah will appoint for him a way out of every distress and a relief from every anxiety, and will provide sustenance for him from sources he does not expect (Abu Dawud Book 20, Hadith 1873 Riyad as-Salihin)

> ... And do not lose hope in the mercy of Allah; indeed none lose hope in the mercy of Allah except the most ungrateful people (Qu'ran 12:87)

> Satan threatens you with poverty and orders you to immorality, while Allah promises you forgiveness from Him and bounty. And Allah is all-Encompassing and Knowing (Qu'ran 2:268)

The shaitaan makes people focus on hopelessness so they would overlook the immense hope that is there of Allah’s mercy.

Following a sin up with goodness also wipes out the bad deed.

> And establish prayer at the two ends of the day and at the approach of the night. Indeed, good deeds do away with misdeeds. That is a reminder for those who remember (Qu'ran 11:114)

> And return [in repentance] to your Lord and submit to Him before the punishment comes upon you; then you will not be helped. (Qu'ran 39: 53-54)

Now, as for sinning during Ramadan, only the main Shaitaan is chained up. The jinns are still there. Also, evil can derive from other sources too (e.g. a evil from one's own soul)

Al-Bukhaari (1899) and Muslim (1079) narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “When Ramadaan comes, the gates of Paradise are opened, the gates of Hell are closed, and the devils are chained up.”

And Allah knows best

Answer (score 0):

It is said in the month of ramadan,the doors of heaven are open,hell closed and the devils chained according to a saying of the prophet muhammad pbuh.
This could mean that people are chaining devils by praying extra and entering heaven and being saved from hellfire.Or it could mean that the devil's evil whispering has stopped and we are doing it ourselves.There are many possibilities.
If you do a sin repent as you would normally as the prophet told us the person who repents is like the one who hasnt sinned and the intention of doing a task is better than the task itself.